# Seeking front end for MinGW gdb debugger

Tags: debuggers

We are unit testing with [Vectorcast](https://www.vectorcast.com/), which uses the MinGW tool chain on Windows.

It launches the command line `gdb`, but some of the newer engineers are having problems getting to grips with something without a GUI.

I am looking for a GUI for the MinGW gdb, which

- runs on Windows
- is free for commercial use
- does not require admin rights
- does not write to the registry (preferably fully portable)
- does not run in the browser

The latter point rules out x64dbg and, I believe OllyDbg. What are our options? We just want to point it at an .EXE, possibly set the source code path, if not in the .EXE, visually set breakpoints, step through code, examine variables, etc.

Comment: Check out [gdbgui](https://gdbgui.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I did, but for some reason, it would not run (perhaps because I do not have admin rights (to runt the server)?). Also, "security" concerns would prohibit running our proprietary code in the browser (yes, I do understand that it runs a local server and never leaves my PC, but I doubt that we could explain that to the Pointy Headed Bosses :-(   I have updated the question to say "no browser, please"

Comment: @Mawg: Have you tried DDD?

Comment: I have been searching for over a decade for a Windows port of DDD. That would be my first choice, but ... Windows :-(